# Listview in alphabetical order

Tags: android, facebook, listview

I have a listview that gets facebook friends, and i would like to sort the names in alphabetical order, but im not very sure how to go on and do this.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
        public void onComplete(List<Profile> friends) {
            // populate list
            List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Profile profile : friends) {
                //profile.getInstalled();
                values.add(profile.getName());
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> friendsListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_items2, values);
            mFriendsList.setAdapter(friendsListAdapter);

        }
    };
```

I have looked around for solutions but didn't find for arraydapter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use `ArrayAdapter.sort`

```
friendsListAdapter.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
        return lhs.compareTo(rhs);    
    }
});
```

Answer (score 9):

you need to create a comparator which sorts lis for you.

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Profile> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Profile p1, Profile p2) {
        return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
    }
}
```

then you just have to do

```
Collections.sort(values, new MyComparator());
```

or simply you can create an anonymous class

```
Collections.sort(values, new Comparator<Profile>(){
    public int compare(Profile p1, Profile p2) {
            return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to sort a simple arraylist of string, just do

```
Collections.sort(values)
```

before passing the list into the ArrayAdapter. 
When the items are rendered in the ListView, it should already display sorted result.

*Additional notes:
If you wish to do complicated sorting on objects, you could use custom sorting by passing implementation of Comparator as second parameter of Collections.sort()

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Comparator`. There you define what to compare and how, in the `compare()` method you define what should be returned from two of your instances. Here's an example for a `String` `Comparator`.

```
new Comparator<String>() {
  public int compare(final String user1, final String user2) {
    // This would return the ASCII representation of the first character of each string
    return (int) user2.charAt(0) - (int) user1.charAt(0);
  };
};
```

Once defined, you simply assign it to the `ListView` by the `.sort()` method. In the case you're using a custom layout, with a custom `Class`, that's what you'll receive as the `compare()` arguments, so the above is just an example to a simple layout with two `String`s. Addapt it to the layout you're using and it will get sorted.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can just use...

```
values.sort()
```